# Handling database connections efficiently

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I am using below helper class for Dapper operations. If there are multiple entities to be mapped to complex DTO object, I am retrieving it individually and attaching to the property manually.

For ex: To retrieve a customer, I have a Customer class with Orders and Addresses property. I know about QueryMultiple method, but in real time we have different queries.

```
 cust.Orders = DapperHelper.ExecList<OrderDTO>(qry1, params1);
 cust.Addresses = DapperHelper.ExecList<AddressDTO>(qry2, params2);
```

My doubt is if I open the connection for populating child items each time will there be any performance hit. Instead, can I initialize connection in the constructor and close it in the dispose method thus utilizing a single connection for each request.

```
 public class DapperHelper
    {
        private static string _conn =  Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbContext"]);


        public static IEnumerable<T> ExecList<T>(string query, object cmdParams = null, CommandType cmdType = CommandType.Text, bool buffered = true)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> list;
            using (IDbConnection _db = new SqlConnection(_conn))
            {
                list = _db.Query<T>(query, param: cmdParams, commandTimeout: 0, commandType: cmdType, buffered: buffered);
                _db.Close();
            }
            return list;
        }

         public static T ExecSingleOrDefault<T>(string query, object cmdParams = null, CommandType cmdType = CommandType.Text)
    {
        T obj;
        using (IDbConnection _db = new SqlConnection(_conn))
        {
            obj = _db.Query<T>(query, param: cmdParams, commandTimeout: 0, commandType: cmdType).SingleOrDefault();
            _db.Close();
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know QueryMultiple why not place your two models in one.

Comment: As mentioned, sometimes we have unrelated data to be populated into DTO's

Comment: SQL Server connections are kept in a pool, so obtaining new connections in your code is not a costly operation. You should always close a DB connection as soon as you are done with it, and not try to keep one open in an attempt to increase performance.

Comment: @JLRishe, Our application is used by 5000 users simultaneously. Would it be still good to have it this way?

Comment: @Sunny Yes, that's all the more reason not to hold onto an SqlConnection any longer than you have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SQLConnection` [automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) use connection pooling by default, so you don't have to worry about the network connection overhead as long as you dispose your connection correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you know QueryMultiple why not place your two models in one like

```
public class CustomerViewModel

   List<Orders> orderList;
   List<Address> addresslit;
end class
```

Then when you call Dapper.Query

Map it as

```
 IEnumerable<CustomrerViewModel> list
```

This way only one sql connection is required